# SQLAlchemy how do I update only certain fields of my record

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model (Company) that has some fields in it.  After creating a Company record, I would like to be able to update this record from a form.  However, if one of the fields is blank, then I would like to just ignore that field and leave the present information.

I have tried to create a `form.py` and then in my `views.py` grab the data from the form which works.  However, when I then try to submit the data, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'update'

I have googled this, but am lost as to why it won't update.  I have searched for the past hour or so and any direction would be awesome.  Thank you.

**Models.py**

```
class Company(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # The email is what connects Company and POC (Buyer)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    company_url = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    # Child relationship to the Event
    duns = db.Column(db.String(11))
    event_id = db.relationship(
        'Events', secondary=event_company, backref='event', lazy='dynamic'
    )
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    buyer = db.relationship('Buyers', backref='buyer', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(
        self, email, company, duns, company_url,
        password
    ):
```

**Form.py**

```
class UpdateCompanyForm(FlaskForm):
    buyer_id = QuerySelectField(
        'POC Name', query_factory=buyer_query, get_pk=get_pk
    )
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Email()])
    company = StringField('Company')
    company_url = StringField('Company Website', validators=[URL(message='Must be a valid URL')])
    duns = StringField('DUNS', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password', validators=[EqualTo('pass_confirm',
                                                        message='Passwords must match')]
    )
    pass_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    submit = SubmitField('Register!')
```

**Views.py**

```
class UpdateCompanyView(MethodView):

    template_file = 'buyers/update_company.html'
    form_class = UpdateCompanyForm

    def get(self, comp_id):
        # This id will autopopulate the company form as an object
        company_id = Company.query.get(comp_id)
        # Need to join this so I have all buyers associated with the company
        buyer = Buyers.query.filter_by(company=comp_id).first()
        return render_template(
            self.template_file, form=self.form_class(obj=company_id),
            buyer=buyer
        )

    def post(self, comp_id):
        form = self.form_class()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            buyers_list = form.buyer_id.data.id

            company_info = Company(
                email=form.email.data,
                company=form.company.data,
                company_url=form.company_url.data,
                duns=form.duns.data,
                password=form.password.data
            )
            db.session.update(company_info)
            db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the record you want to update and then set the attributes:

```
def post(self, comp_id):
    form = self.form_class()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        buyers_list = form.buyer_id.data.id

        company_info = Company.query.get(comp_id)
        company_info.email = form.email.data
        ....
        db.session.commit()
```

If you need to ignore blank fields you might be able to do something like:

```
 company_info = Company.query.get(comp_id)
 #Ignore form fields not in data model
 form_data = {i: form.data[i] for i in form.data if i not in ["csrf_token", "submit"]}
 #Remove empty fields
 new_data = {k: v for k, v in form_data.items() if v is not None}
 #Unpack into Company model
 company_info.update(**new_data)
 db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you, PGHE.  This makes sense.  I am running into a validator issue.  Basically, in my forms I have `validators=[URL(message='Must be a valid URL')])`.  Of course, if I don't enter data it catches this error.  Should I move this error catching into my view.py instead?

Comment: If it's an optional field, you could add the `Optional()` validator. Form-validation isn't 'error-catching' per se. You should try have client-side validation so a user can see what they've done wrong, but you must have server-side validation to protect your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the company object through a query, update the attributes where you need them and then commit the session.

```
 def post(self, comp_id):
        form = self.form_class()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            buyers_list = form.buyer_id.data.id
            
            company = Company.query.filter_by(id=comp_id)
            
            company.email=form.email.data,
            company.company=form.company.data,
            company.company_url=form.company_url.data,
            company.duns=form.duns.data,
            company.password=form.password.data
                
            db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Please fix those lines `company.email=form.email.data,` that comma at the end of the value becomes it in a tuple.